# Why CTE (recursive) is not parallelized (MAXDOP=8)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

We have rather Big machine 100GB+ memory and 8+ cores in it. Server wide MAXDOP=8.

```
T_SEQ_FF rowcount = 61692209, size = 2991152 KB
```

**UPD 1:** 
Table `T_SEQ_FF` have two indexes:

```
1) create index idx_1 on T_SEQ_FF (first_num)
2) create index idx_2 on T_SEQ_FF (second_num)
```

Table `T_SEQ_FF` have `first_num`, `second_num pairs` of nums that should provide a sequence after cte:

```
;with first_entity as ( 
    select first_num from  T_SEQ_FF a  where not exists (select 1 from  T_SEQ_FF b  where a.first_num = b.second_num) 
) ,
cte as ( 
select a.first_num, a.second_num, a.first_num as first_key, 1 as sequence_count 
from  T_SEQ_FF a  inner join first_entity b on a.first_num = b.first_num 
union all 
select a.first_num, a.second_num, cte.first_key, cte.sequence_count + 1 
from  T_SEQ_FF a  
inner join cte on a.first_num = cte.second_num 
) 
select * 
from cte 
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

But when I run this query - I only see serial query plan without Parallelism. 
If I **remove** 2nd part of CTE from query above:

```
union all 
    select a.first_num, a.second_num, cte.first_key, cte.sequence_count + 1 
    from  T_SEQ_FF a  
    inner join cte on a.first_num = cte.second_num
```

then I could see that query plan becomes **Parallelized** using Repartition and Gather Streams.

So I can summarize that it is because of **recurisve** CTE SQL Server is not using Parallelism when processing this query.

I believe that on such big machine with tons of free resources Parallelism should help to finish query faster.

For now it runs for ~40-50mins.

Could you advice how to use as much resources as we can to finish the query faster?

CTE is the only option because we need to populate sequences from `first_num - second_num` pairs and those sequences could be of any length.

Comment: Do you have index on T_SEQ_FF.second_num?

Comment: Yes I've added index creation clauses that we use into topic.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the **recursive** part, not the fact that it's a CTE.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, my mistake - I'm calling that CTE having in mind "Recursive CTE". So why SQL server can't at least parallelize SCAN table(index) for preparation step for Recursion part??? Why the whole query is serial.

Comment: @zmische - I'm guessing so this isn't an answer, but I think it's because the second query depends on the first.  Since the second inner joins the first, they don't run at the same time.  It makes more sense from an efficiency standpoint to limit the rows returned by the `INNER JOIN` than to run both simultaneously and then filter out invalid rows.

Comment: Seems reasonable. That's pity.

Comment: Well, if you can't optimize this query with a recursive CTE, then perhaps you should reconsider using it. Is it really needed, or if that is the only way to do it in sql server, then perhaps it can be done in another platform/ framework? Hadroop, NOSQL, what not?
Perhaps you should rather post a new question with details on what data you have and what you want to perform on it, and let the community suggest altenatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try rewriting the CTE to remove one of the steps i.e.

```
;cte as ( 
select a.first_num, a.second_num, a.first_num as first_key, 1 as sequence_count 
from  T_SEQ_FF a  where not exists (select 1 from  T_SEQ_FF b  where a.first_num = b.second_num) 
union all 
select a.first_num, a.second_num, cte.first_key, cte.sequence_count + 1 
from  T_SEQ_FF a  
inner join cte on a.first_num = cte.second_num 
) 
select * 
from cte 
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

If there is only one root element it would be better to pass this into the query as a variable so the value can be used by the query optimizer.

Another thing to try is change the query to get the root elements without a subquery i.e. second_num is null or first_num = second_num.

Comment: I just tried your query - same result as before - serial plan. We saved one HASH Join though that should possibly help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this i a viable option, but we have already ruled out many other conventional approaches: Can you do a explicit parallelization by splitting the first_entity set into pieces, and then running this query in parallel by code, and finally merge these datasets together.

This is quite more complex than just a t-sql solution, and I don't know if this will work on you data, both data distribution and locking might be issues here.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a similar problem and after careful analyzing the situation as well as the problem in [UNION ALL Performance IN SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205980/union-all-performance-in-sql-server-2005/9196760#9196760) it appears to me that referencing a cte in a UNION ALL query turns off parallelization (most likely that it is a bug).